# Possible reason for failed ajax request with https protocol but http works

Tags: php, jquery, apache, codeigniter, https

Currently I am working on installing https for a site which is based on codeigniter and apache under Linux environment.

I've checked the configuration of my certificates by https://www.digicert.com/help/ and most pages work fine.

But one page that would require three pages from the same site through jQuery ajax request failed to fetch content from these three sources. In chrome console it show following message.

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
```

or

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED
```

While the same code and page works perfectly with http protocol.

I usually can see content from 1-2 sources at most. But it can not get all of them successfully.

I modified to preform the ajax request again once it fails. But the failed resource would be simply empty content with http status code 200, which means the browser gets the header successfully but failed to fetch content, or the content originally is empty...

So the issue should be caused by apache configuration for https or something relevant to https.

Another strange thing is IE 10 works fine. But failed on Chrome and FireFox.

I've tried to disable apache module reqtimeout. So I don't think it is caused by longer processing time for https protocol.

And it is not an issue about https call http function, they are all https resources.

If anyone can give me some suggestion for further testing or explanation for possible reason? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did u get the solution?

Comment: Yes, I posted below. Hope it can help someone who also encounters the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, it is a server issue.

I noticed that I only got trouble with failed ajax or iframe requests on Ubuntu 12.10 installed Apache 2.2.

The exact same code can run on a testing serve which is ubuntu 14.04 installed Apache 2.4. So that took me some day to transfer all data and service to a new server to fix the problem.

Since we need the server to run and minimize the cost for server. So I didn't spend a lot of time to figure out what was the reason for the problem.